# Abstract algebra, order of element

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

I have to find the order of elements and cyclic groups but I need some help as I am not sure how to do it right.

We have the elements:
\begin{gather}
w=\cos(2\pi/98) + i\sin(2\pi/98) \\
\alpha = w^4
\end{gather}
and the cyclic groups:
\begin{align}
G &= \langle w\rangle\\
H &= \langle \alpha\rangle
\end{align}

Could you please explain me how to do it the right way?

Comment: $w=e^{2\pi i/98}$ is a primitive $98$-th root of unity.

Answer (score 1):

Notice $w^k = \cos (\frac {k*2\pi}{98}) + i(\frac {k*2\pi}{98})$ and $w^{98} = 1$ and that if $1 \le k < j <98$ then $w^k \ne w^j$.

That tells you that $<w> = \{1,w, w^2, ..... , w^{97}\}$ with $|w| = 98$.

And notice $(w^4)^k =  \cos (\frac {2k*2\pi}{49}) + i(\frac {2k*2\pi}{49})$.  And if $k > 25$ then $(w^4)^k =  \cos (\frac {2k*2\pi}{49}) + i(\frac {2k*2\pi}{49})=\cos(\frac {2k*2\pi}{49} - 2\pi) + i(\frac {2k*2\pi}{49}-2\pi)$. with $(w^4)^{49} = 1$ and that if $1 \le k < j < 49$ then $(w^4)^k \ne (w^4)^j$.

So $<w^4> = \{1,w^4, w^8,..., w^{96}, w^2, w^6, .....,w^{94}\}$

Answer (score 1):

Since $w^{98}=1$ and $w^{k}\ne1$ for $0<k<98$ (use De Moivre’s formula), we see that $w$ has order $98$ and so
$$
\langle w\rangle=\{w^k:0\le k<98\}
$$
Also $\alpha^{49}=(w^{4})^{49}=(w^{98})^2=1^2=1$. Hence the order of $\alpha$ is a divisor of $49$. However it can be neither $1$ nor $7$, because $\alpha=w^4\ne1$ and $\alpha^7=w^{28}\ne1$.

Hence the order is $49$ and $\langle\alpha\rangle=\{\alpha^k:0\le k<49\}$.

I exploited the fact that if $g^n=1$, with $n>0$, then the order of $g$ is a divisor of $n$.

More generally, if $g$ has order $m$, then the order of $g^n$ is $m/\!\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: Can I ask, what's the algorithm of finding the subgroups of G? Should I find the factors of 98?

Comment: @SuperMan A finite cyclic group of order $n$ has a unique subgroup of order $d$, for each divisor $d$ of $n$. If $g$ is a generator for the group, the unique subgroup of order $d$ is generated by $g^{n/d}$.